# Receive USB control request /usb messages in my activity/service

Tags: android, embedded, usb, arduino

**If I connect two android USB devices(via OTG cable) can I receive the control request sent from one device in my activity/service running in the other phone**?.I went through all apis but couldn't figure out how .

In android sdk sample application MissileLauncher , app send a control request to a USB device, but there is no example how to read these control requests.